# Need a Simple speech to text software

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Can someone help me to find a solution that I can use for entering words or characters. Looking for an open source solution preferrebly java based.

I was looking for an application that enter character's simply as  " a A b B 1 8 " or words as apple php etc...

Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing as "simple" in voice recognition - not if you want it to be actually usable. It is also a field with high requirements in both theory and development, so there are not many open source projects out there.

Now, as far as Java voice-recognition software goes, you can have a look at [CMU Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/).

Comment: I will look the Sphinx Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an API take a look at Java's Text-to-Speech API:

> http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapifaq.html

If you are actually asking for a software here (i.e. you dont have to program anything) you should repost on Superuser.

Comment: This is only an API, however. You still need to get the software that will provide the Voice Recognition engine. In addition, most of the listed projects in that page are ages old and are Text-To-Speech only.